# How can I find the number of emails sent daily on Terminal

Tags: macos, email, terminal

I am using Terminal on Mac and I would like to know the number of emails sent daily from my Mail app.

Would it be possible to find out the number of emails sent from Mail using the Terminal? For the past week, past month and for the past year?